# How to fix syntax error parsing JPQL with group by

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm new using JPA and JPQL for a project, but I got SQL syntax error and I couldn't find the cause.

I'm using spring boot, MySQL.

I got a vote repository

```
public interface VoteRepository extends JpaRepository<Vote, Long> {
    ....

    @Query(value = "SELECT NEW com.self.polls.model.ChoiceVoteCount(v.choice.id, count(v.id)) FROM Vote v WHERE v.poll.id = :pollId GROUP BY v.choice.id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ChoiceVoteCount> countByPollIdGroupByChoiceId(@Param("pollId") Long pollId);

    ....
}
```

ChoiceVoteCount

```
public class ChoiceVoteCount {
     private Long choiceId;

    private Long voteCount;    
}
```

Vote

```
public class Vote {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "poll_id", nullable = false)
    private Poll poll;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "choice_id", nullable = false)
    private Choice choice;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

But I got error when running this query

```
2019-03-27 16:01:34.783 ERROR 68064 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.self.polls.model.ChoiceVoteCount(v.choice.id, count(v.id)) FROM Vote v WHERE v.' at line 1
2019-03-27 16:01:34.787 ERROR 68064 --- [nio-5000-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.self.polls.model.ChoiceVoteCount(v.choice.id, count(v.id)) FROM Vote v WHERE v.' at line 1
```

Comment: remove the `nativeQuery = true` since you are using jpql.

Comment: but when I remove it, I got another error
```
Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Map com.self.polls.repository.VoteRepository.countByPollIdGroupByChoiceId()!
``` when I start the Application

Comment: sorry I found that caused by a type error. it shows up by removing nativeQuery. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a constructor in ChoiceVoteCount.
To play safe, the default constructor could also be added.

```
public ChoiceVoteCount() {
}

public ChoiceVoteCount(Long choiceId, Long voteCount) {
    this.choiceId = choiceId;
    this.voteCount = voteCount;
}
```